# Add color to selected <li> item / override <ul> style

Tags: html, css

I have navigation for which I need to set a color for the selected item.  It's flat HTML and CSS.

Here's the menu code:

```
 <ul id="top_navigation">
     <li class="border_red"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="border_red"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li class="border_red"><a href="services.html"><font color="#cf3533">Services</font></a></li>
     <li class="border_red"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
     <li class="border_red"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
     <li class="border_red"><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
```

And here's the CSS - there's the basic  set up and then a class to put the pipe between the items:

```
#top_navigation {
   width: 696px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0 0 0 4px;
   list-style-type: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#top_navigation li {
   width: auto;
   height: 17px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 1px 10px 0 10px;
   float: left;
}

#top_navigation li a {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   display: block;
   font-size: 12px;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
}

#top_navigation li a:hover {
   color: #cf3533;
}
```

This sets the pipe on the right.

```
.border_red {
   border-right: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
```

I tried combining the two and creating a _selected style, and the pipe shows up, but I can't get the color to change for the selected.

I have to be WCAG Priorities 1,2,3-compliant, so I can't just set it manually with `<font>`.

Comment: How do you know which is the selected item?  By "selected" do you mean the hover color (i.e. the mouse is currently over the link)?

Comment: Can I ask why are you using deprecated `<font>` element?

Comment: <font> is deprecated in XHTML 1.0 with strict doctype, maybe he's using pure HTML.

Answer (score 2):

With "flat" HTML and CSS only, this can't be done. You can do this by inserting some server-side code to add a "current" class to the current navigation item, or you can do it with JavaScript by comparing the `window.location` to the `href` of the links.

Answer (score 0):

To find out where particular element inherits its style from, open [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (Firefox) or Web Inspector (Safari), select the element, and you will see list of its styles and their origins. Overwritten styles are marked with strike-through text.

A site note: CSS class name should tell what the element is, not how it looks. Instead of repeating `border_red` class, consider the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

With CSS:

```
ul li {
    border-left: .1em solid red;
}

ul li.first {
    border-left: 0;
}

ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;  /* If support for ancient browsers is not needed */
}
```